# JavaScript - Global modifier not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a PHP Syntax Highlighter code in JavaScript. Here is what I have tried:

```html
<html>

<head>

    <title>Untitled 1</title>

<script>
function showContents(text) {
    var string = /\"[a-z0-9A-Z!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]*\"/i;
    var aVariable = /\$([a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)/i;
    var output = text;
    if(aVariable.test(output)==true)
    {
        output = output.replace(aVariable.exec(output)[0],"<font color='blue'>"+aVariable.exec(output)[0]+"</font>");
        document.getElementById("UserInput").innerHTML = output;
    }
    if(string.test(output)==true)
    {
        output = output.replace(string.exec(output)[0],"<font color='red'>"+string.exec(output)[0]+"</font>");
        document.getElementById("UserInput").innerHTML = output;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("UserInput").innerHTML = output;
    }
    document.write(output);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="UserInput"></div>
<form>
<textarea onkeyup="showContents(this.value)"></textarea></form>

</body>
</html>
```

The above script is working fine for inputs like:

```
$name="ABC"
```

However, if I try inputs like:

```
$name="ABC";$name2="CDE"
```

The code is highlighting only the first instance (ie `$name="ABC"`). Changing the modifier to global is not giving output itself.

Comment: Once you do the first replace, you have a HTML string, not a plain text string. And then [it's no longer possible to use regex to parse it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630) in order to do more replaces. You need a proper parser, not regex.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with `aVariable.exec(output)[0]` you only return the first match, and pass that to the `replace` method for replacement. As this code is only executed once, a second match is never processed.

It is better to pass regular expressions to `replace` directly and not the result of `exec` (which is an array of string). Also you could benefit from the possibility to pass a callback function to `replace` so you can execute code on each match for wrapping the `font` tag around it.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
function htmlEncode(text) {
    // Uses the DOM to correctly escape HTML special characters (e.g. ampersand, less-than) 
    var elm = document.createElement('span');
    elm.textContent = text;
    return elm.innerHTML;
}

function formatContents(text) {
    // Use one regexp for all, and modify the matches with a call back function:
    return text.replace(/(\"(\\"|.)*?\")|(\$([\w\x7f-\xff]*))/g, function (match, str, vari) {
        var color = str ? 'red' : 'blue';
        return "<font color='" + color + "'>" + htmlEncode(match) + "</font>";
    });
}

function showContents() {
    // Take contents from textarea and display formatted in UserInput div:
    document.getElementById("UserInput").innerHTML = 
        formatContents(document.getElementById("input").value);
}

document.getElementById("input").oninput = showContents;
// Apply upon page load
showContents();
```

```html
The formatting is done as you type:<br>
<textarea id="input" style="width:100%">$name="ABC";
$name2="CDE"</textarea>
<div id="UserInput" style="white-space: pre"></div>
```

I changed the "string" regular expression a bit, as it is easier to pass a negative list of characters than a positive one.

The advantage of doing the replace in regular expression, is that once you have a match, that substring will not be matched again for something else (a variable is never a string literal, and vice versa).